# Tutorial/Manual how to create Visualizer in autoexp.dat

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have some C++ datatypes for which I would like to improve the debugging experience in my team. I therefore want to create a custom visualizer in the autoexp.dat file. The [AutoExpand] section doesn't seem sufficient, so I started to look at [Visualizer]. I found [this website](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120) with some explanations, but is there any comprehensive reference/manual/tutorial? I don't get the difference between $c and $e, for example. I already succeeded in displaying some basic information, but I feel like there's so much more to know...

Do you know any good resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for your information, in addition to boost sandbox link in virtualdub.org you quoted, [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers)

Comment: As for the difference between $c and $e, there is a note at
[followup note](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=172)
(sorry, if you've already seen it).

Comment: no, I haven't seen this! Thanks a lot! You can make it an answer, if you want!

Comment: The MSDN documentation says you can use `[Visualizer]`s only with_managed_ code.  For _native C++_, you're supposedly stuck with `[AutoExpand]` rules.  That doesn't seem consistent with the any of the comments, answers, or sites linked from here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appears this is already commented above but someone coming to this question would not necessarily read the comments and so might miss the great tutorial available on the boost site:

[https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers](https://web.archive.org/web/20220912040244/https://svn.boost.org/trac10/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers)

Also

http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2007/04/06/tweaking-autoexpdat-for-custom-types-in-vs2005/

http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/how-to-set-up-visual-studio-debugger-visualizers

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=172

Comment: A very useful information regarding to VS2008 SP1 is the _vcee_autoexp environment variable. Credits: https://vtk.org/Wiki/ITK/Debug_Visualizers_for_Visual_Studio

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of visualizer for boost::tuple.  It should be fairly easy to follow:

```
boost::tuples::tuple<*>{
    ; Show as (11, 22, 33, ... })
    preview (
        #(
            "("
            , $e.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ", "
            , $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , ")"
        )
    )   
    children (
        #(
            0: $e.head
            , 1: $e.tail.head
            , 2: $e.tail.tail.head
            , 3: $e.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 4: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 5: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 6: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 7: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 8: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
            , 9: $e.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head
        )
    )
}
```