# How do you setup Intellisense to display custom data-types in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, intellisense, variant

There's a way to make it so intellisense will behave appropriately for custom data-types in a similar way, for example, variants will display VT_I4 for a variant that is of type "int".

I'm trying to get intellisense to be more useful for my custom array data-type.  So another similar case is the vector class, how it shows its contents appropriately and I don't have to use the Watch windows to access different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the file **autoexp.dat**, and add entries to this file for your own datatypes.

The following explanation helped me a lot: [Writing custom visualizers for Visual Studio 2005](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120). The file itself contains a lot of documentation about the format as well.

VS2008 and VS2010 use the same file and the same format.

BTW: I recommend to **make a backup of the original file** before you start modifying it.

UPDATE: Searching for **autoexp.dat** on SO reveals a lot of information. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6271789/396551) has several more links.