# visual studio 2010 express c++ , doesn't show variable values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, variables

i just started to use 2010 vc express c++ but i can't find how and where do i config it to see the   variable values , the same variables i used to see in the 2008 version out of the box.

[image]

Comment: I see loads of variable values in your screenshot?

Comment: I see variable values, what are you talking about?

Comment: If you're complaining about the Qt data structure display, you should mention (actually, stress) that in your question.

Comment: Could this be related to a Visual Studio 2010 bug? Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2452649 or http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2452649

Comment: no .. no... i suppose to see the value of the QString

Comment: @andre its for net , im using c++

Comment: Sorry, but it is really for Visual Studio C++ 2010, I have used it myself... I am however unsure if it is your issue nor if the problem occurs in the Express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the fact that it shows Qt data structures in "raw" format instead of nicely formatted. You would need to download and install the Qt VS add-in to enable the better formatting, but that doesn't work with VS Express edition.

I've never used Express, but if it uses `autoexp.dat`, you might be able to smuggle the contents of the Qt add-in into there, or write your own. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4883238/1782465) and its answers could provide more hints.