# visual studio watch member of structure in an array

Tags: c, visual-studio

I was wondering if there is a way in Visual Studio to see a specific member in a structure for an array of structures.
For example: 
if I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct str_t
{
   int a;
   int b;
} str;
```

and a global variable of:

```
str structure[10] = {0};
```

So I would like to see in the watch list the member 'a' in all the elements in the array.
like this:

```
structure[0].a             0
structure[1].a             0
structure[2].a             0
...
```

without creating each one desperately

While it's a simple structure like the one I referred to above, it's very simple. 
If I watch the array in the 'watch' list I can see in the value the entire structure.
But if the structure is more complex Visual Studio adds "..." at the end because it doesn't fit in the window.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Uri

Comment: too busy for a full answer, but google autoexp.dat or see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2dd308b2-330e-435e-a245-83cc1adbd5b8/tutorial-on-using-autoexpdat

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2022, add a watch for the array/list/whatever that you are interested in.

Expand the watch list, then expand the first element. Click the pin on the element field that you want to see.

[image: Expanded list showing pin]

All other elements will be automatically filtered to only show that field.

[image: Expanded list showing filtered fields]

You can pin multiple fields and they will be shown comma-separated on one line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class ComplexExample
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Size{ get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var complexities = new List<ComplexExample>();
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex1", Size = 10, Price = 100 });
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex2", Size = 20, Price = 200 });
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex3", Size = 30, Price = 300 });
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex4", Size = 40, Price = 400 });
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex5", Size = 50, Price = 500 });
            complexities.Add(new ComplexExample { Name = "Complex6", Size = 60, Price = 600 });

            Console.WriteLine(complexities.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, never knew about this one. Extremely helpful in our 200k+ lines codebase with many complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom formatters for the debugger window... quick google [says this is a good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883238/tutorial-manual-how-to-create-visualizer-in-autoexp-dat)

So you'd create a formatter for your struct that only displayed the a member, then you can see it in the watch list. Note, if you add a ",10" at the end of ytour array variable, it will expand to show (in this case) the first 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom visualizer for your data each time you want to debug something, it looks like you can do what you did above, and then quickly "pin" member variables as "favorite".

After you pin a couple of favorites, there's a button to "Show only pinned members", which will let you filter for the parts of the struct you want.