# Why won't Visual Studio's debugging show me my floats as just simple decimal values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, floating-point

I am setting floats and visual studios while debugging always just shows me this big notation like.

-4.3176166e+008
-4.3160208e+008

rather than

-0.605
-0.789

Is there any way I can just see my values in decimal rather than that other notation.

Comment: [(3./2.), f](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx) may work. anyway just **google** things. when you find **documentation** that's where to look first!

Comment: Most any question about the way floating point numbers behave can be answered by keeping a simple principle in mind, *float* can store 7 digits, *double* can store 15 digits.  So the debugger will not display an integral number with 8 digits, that would be lying about accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Because -4.3176166e+008 != -0.605.  If your value was -0.605, it would be displayed like that, but for values with a large number of significant figures, it is easier to read in *scientific notation* - you don't have to count the digits, and you can compare maginitude quickly and easily by comparing the exponent.

You examples in standard notation are:

-431761660 and -431602080

Not so bad maybe, but for very small or very large numbers, it is beneficial, and the line has to be drawn somewhere.  For example 1.0e-20 is much easier to comprehend than 0.00000000000000000001  (and if I have got that wrong, it rather proves my point).

It is not peculiar to Visual Studio; your pocket scientific calculator will do the same thing - it has to as it has a limited width display.  So Visual Studio's behaviour is also useful for when you are comparing results in your code with values calculated by hand on a calculator.

Another reason for representing numbers in this way is that binary floating point representations have precision limited to about 6 decimal digits for float and 15 for double, to display a greater number of significant digits would be misleading.

Comment: Yeah but my visual studios use to show me these values in decimal value I haven't changed the floating values. So i want to assume that the visual studios setting changed or something. I know it was in a scientific notation. But for debugging sake its not going to help me its in this format

Comment: Why won't it help?  It's exactly the same value.  I somehow doubt that this changed on it own, but the fact that you believe it has is important information missing from your original question. It may have changed between versions - you mention *Visual Studios" (plural) - are you using more than one version?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the Visual Studio debugger shows numbers in a certain way, then there is the `autoexp.dat` file that Visual Studio uses to determine how to display values in the debugger.  Changing the definitions in this file will change how variables are displayed.

Here is a tutorial on using autoexp.dat:

http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83

These links describes the new Visualizer, but mentions autoexp.dat:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx
[Tutorial/Manual how to create Visualizer in autoexp.dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883238/tutorial-manual-how-to-create-visualizer-in-autoexp-dat)

Comment: is there anyway i can just get the default visual studios one reloaded? because i figure if i can just get the default ones working again they will be ok. i never touched those files but no idea what else i can test

Comment: You are more than likely using the default ones already.  Just save the current autoexp.dat somewhere, and experiment with the autoexp.dat with new settings.  If it doesn't work out for you, just replace the changed file with the old file.

Comment: Links are not valid anymore. Here's an updated relevant link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer not to deal with scientific notation mentally, and don't want to change the Visual Studio settings, use a spreadsheet.

Paste the number into a cell, and set the cell format to taste. For example, pasting `-4.3176166e+008` into a LibreOffice Calc cell and setting the cell format to "Number" shows `-431761660`. This has the advantage that you can easily change the format as you are viewing numbers, and display numbers in the same format even if they came from different contexts in different original formats.

A spreadsheet is often useful anyway when debugging numerical programs, for doing quick calculations and keeping the results visible.