# QString does not show value during debugging - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

The QString does not show the value of it in Debug mode.

[image]

I have tested the same project on another machine, also with Visual Studio 2010 - it is working there. I can see the value of the QString in debug mode.

So I think, it might be a Visual Studio setting. I am using Qt 4.7 on both machines.

Comment: The [autoexp.dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883238/tutorial-manual-how-to-create-visualizer-in-autoexp-dat) file is responsible for displaying user-defined types in the debugger for VS 2010.  Does yours have a definition for `QString`?

Comment: The QString is defined in qstring.h in Qt 4.7. It is not made by me.

Comment: This seems to be solved here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/18954/solved-visual-studio-debug-helpers-qt5-and-qstring

Comment: is this during with the "debug" configuration? Some of the optimizations that are enabled in "release" configuration make the debugger display wrong values. Also, QString is not defined by Visual Studio, so from the perspective of Visual Studio it is user-defined

Comment: @ transistor:

Thank you, that was my problem :)

Comment: @Makuna, it looks like you use rather Qt5 than Qt4, but you insisted that it's Qt4.7.

Comment: @Makuna *The QString is defined in qstring.h in Qt 4.7. It is not made by me* -- But `QString` is not a Microsoft invention.  Any types that are not maintained by Microsoft and/or the Visual Studio engineers w.r.t. the debugger are user-defined.